# WooCommerce Authorize.net C I M Gateway Authorize.net Payment Failed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

Plugin Name - Woo Commerce Authorize.net C I M Gateway

Error MSG - Authorize.net Payment Failed (Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)).

Please provide us some solutions.

Comment: Have you recently installed updates to your server without restarting?

Answer (score 1):

You should try restarting Apache (or nginx). If that fails, restart the server.

http://blog.getclef.com/fix-problem-ssl-ca-cert-path-access-rights-error/